# AsynckTask Runtime exception for doInBackground

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I've looked at other questions but this error seems code specific so I'm kind of frustrated.I've been working on an app that simply reverse google searches an certain image.

MainActivity

```
    package com.example.ygoc95.myapplication;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.provider.Settings;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;



    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;

    import static android.R.attr.bitmap;
    import org.jibble.simpleftp.*;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private File resim;
private String path,yol;
private ImageView iv;
private Bitmap bm;
private Button send;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resim);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.url);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    resim = new File(path, "url.jpg");

    OutputStream fOut = null;
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(resim);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
    try {
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}




@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    send.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View paramV) {
            Context a=getApplicationContext();
            new async(a).execute(resim);


        }
    }));


}

       }
```

AsyckTask

```
 package com.example.ygoc95.myapplication;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.support.annotation.NonNull;


 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.client.params.HttpClientParams;
 import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
 import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.math.MathContext;


 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 public class async extends AsyncTask<File,File,File> {
private static final String UPLOAD_IMAGE_URL =           "https://www.google.ca/searchbyimage/upload";
private Context mContext;
public  String resultsURL;
public async(Context a) {
    mContext=a;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

private HttpResponse uploadImage(File imageFile) throws IOException {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(UPLOAD_IMAGE_URL);

    HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(post.getParams(), false);


    org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity entity = new org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart("encoded_image", new FileBody(imageFile));
    entity.addPart("image_url",new StringBody(""));
    entity.addPart("image_content",new StringBody(""));
    entity.addPart("filename",new StringBody(""));
    entity.addPart("h1",new StringBody("en"));
    entity.addPart("bih",new StringBody("179"));
    entity.addPart("biw",new StringBody("1600"));


    post.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(post);

    return response;


}
private File exportToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {

    File resizedImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),"face.png");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(resizedImageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { // TODO
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resizedImageFile;

}



private String getResultsURL(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String resultsURL = "";
    try {

        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf("https://www.google.ca/search?tbs=sbi") > 0) {
                resultsURL = line.substring(9, line.length() - 12);
                continue;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        rd.close();
    }

    return resultsURL;
}



private void openResultsPage(String resultsURL) {
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(resultsURL));
    mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);
}



@Override
protected File doInBackground(File... params) {

    File image =params[0];
    String fileyol=image.getAbsolutePath();
    Bitmap shrunkBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileyol);
    File resizedImage = exportToInternalStorage(shrunkBitmap, "resized_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    String path = resizedImage.getAbsolutePath();

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = uploadImage(resizedImage);
        resultsURL = getResultsURL(response);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
    super.onPostExecute(file);
    openResultsPage(resultsURL);



}
 }
```

Logcat

```
04-24 15:19:32.538 5194-5344/com.example.ygoc95.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
                                                                                at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:89)
                                                                                at com.example.ygoc95.myapplication.async.uploadImage(async.java:60)
                                                                                at com.example.ygoc95.myapplication.async.doInBackground(async.java:135)
                                                                                at com.example.ygoc95.myapplication.async.doInBackground(async.java:38)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Code may be messy a little since I tried many other things and deleted.At the end of the error it says Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType but I don't know if this has anything to do with it. I changed the activity intent to post execute, (thought UI codes may be dangerous in doInbackground) but it didnt help. I really appreciate any help/guide, I'm kinda new to android programming so sorry If there may be simple mistakes.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please edit your original post to include your Logcat output?

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` means that you are referencing a class that can't be found. Since Android 5 (I think) everything from `org.apache.http` is deprecated. However, at the declaration of your AsyncTask, you suppress deprecation warnings: `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`. There's something you can add to your gradle file in the dependencies scope, I think that's something you could try: `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`. I would advice though to stop using these classes and move on to `HttpConnection`

Comment: @Drew Oh,sorry. Edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to access org.apache.http.entity.ContentType with a minimum android API version that no longer includes it. Either replace this class with something new and supported (preferred), or lower your minimum/target API level.